# How can I print the hours of the day in a html table column?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to create a basic schedule webapp. Right now I do have something like this: [image]

The top row sub header is an array of people which I get from a DB. But the left header (hours of the day) is basically generated by reading a string array with the hours of the day in it.

My question be: is there a more "elegant" way of getting the hours of the day?

HTML code:

```
<table class="table-schedule">
    <tr>
        <td style="border-left:none;"></td>
        <th scope="col" ng-repeat="empleado in Empleados" style="font-size:13px; font-weight:600; text-transform:uppercase;">{{empleado.nombres}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody ng-repeat="hora in PorHoras track by $index">
        <tr>
            <th scope="rowgroup" rowspan="2" style="font-size:14px; font-weight:300;">{{hora}}</th>
            <td ng-repeat="empleado in Empleados" data-ng-click="ModalAgendarCita()"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td ng-repeat="empleado in Empleados" data-ng-click="ModalAgendarCita()"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

AngularJs Controller code:

```
$scope.PorHoras = ["06:00 AM", "07:00 AM", "08:00 AM", "09:00 AM", "10:00 AM", "11:00 AM", "12:00 PM",
            "01:00 PM", "02:00 PM", "03:00 PM", "04:00 PM", "05:00 PM", "06:00 PM", "00:00 AM", "07:00 PM",
            "08:00 PM", "09:00 PM", "10:00 PM"];
```

EDIT:

I forget to clarify something. If someone clic inside a Cell a pop up will appear. I will need to capture the "hour" to put it in a timepicker and the "Name" above.

[image]

Comment: If that array is truly representative of your real application, then I would use what you have. Should `00:00 AM` really go where it is shown in the array?

Comment: The thing is, Later I wil need to "read" the hour of that cell to put it in a time picker (input type="time"). So, if someone clic in a cell, I'm going to need the name of the person in the subheader above (easy because the name is binded) BUT would I be able to do the same with the hour? If I clic in a cell, a modal will pop up.

Comment: Yes. Use DOM traversal method appropriate for your language (jQuery, vanilla js, angularjs).